# Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell with EXO V2 Powershell Module under Linux - Connect-IPPSSession

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet, powershell-module

Im trying to connect to the Online PowerShell with the EXO V2 Powershell module using the **Connect-IPPSSession** Cmdlet with certificates. Under Windows everything works fine when using the 2.0.6-Preview5 PreRelease of the OnlineExchangeManagement Module. Under Linux I get the following error with the PreRelease version when executing Connect-IPPSSession:

```
ConnectExchangeOnline: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'CertificateThumbprint'.
```

The command used:

```
Connect-IPPSSession -CertificatePassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'password' -AsPlainText -Force) -CertificateFilePath "/home/.../certificate.pfx"
```

Get-InstalledModule returns:

```
Version              Name                                Repository           Description
-------              ----                                ----------           -----------
2.0                  CredentialManager                   PSGallery            Provides access to credentials in the Windows Credential Manager
2.3.0                PSWSMan                             PSGallery            Module to install and manage the forked WSMan client libraries for Linux and macOS.…
2.0.6-Preview5       ExchangeOnlineManagement            PSGallery            This is a Public Preview release of Exchange Online PowerShell V2 module.…
```

Are the PreRelease versions not usable under Linux?

Comment: On the doc here https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/powershell/module/exchange/connect-ippssession?view=exchange-ps it is stated: "Note: The CertificateThumbprint parameter is supported only in Microsoft Windows."
I assume the certificatethumbprint tell your script to use a certificate from the certificate store of your windows computer. AFAIK there is no such store under Linux. You should instead use the certificatePath and certificatePassword parameters. (with proper permissions on certificate file).
Just curious, does this works on your linux ? Get-ChildItem Cert:/LocalMachine/

Comment: @Brice I totally missed the note regarding windows. But when I execute the following statement: Connect-IPPSSession -CertificatePassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'password' -AsPlainText -Force) -CertificateFilePath "/home/.../certificate.pfx" Im Getting: Connect-ExchangeOnline: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'CertificateThumbprint'.